# select row from array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to print the fourth row of the following array of arrays using a defined method, perhaps within a class.

```
array_of_arrays = [
  ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  ["g", "h", "y", "t"],
  ["p", "v", "b", "q"],
  ["z", "z", "z", "z"]
]
```

I tried several, but it will not work because I need to call a specific row in the method.  Although I'm familiar with chaining methods like (.slice), I need to define a method within a class that will yield the expected row.  I've tried experimenting with hashes and blocks, but they don't seem to work for my solutions.  I'm really reaching out for alternatives.  Thanks!

```
hsh = {}
array_of_arrays.each { |x| hsh[x[0]] = x[1]}

p array_of_arrays.map { |row| row[2]  }

p array_of_arrays { |row|  row.values }

hsh_boggled = {}
array_of_arrays.each do |x|
  key = x[0]
  val = x[1]
hsh_boggled[key] = val
end
```

So, I would like to define a method that can call a given row; so calling row 4 from array_of_arrays with a method would output  ["z", "z", "z", "z"].  Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think `puts array_of_arrays[3]` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I need it to be reported like so ["z", "z", "z", "z"]

Comment: What do you think has the `hsh =...` code snippet to do with the solution? I recommend that you take some time and rethink your problem and its requirements.

Comment: I didn't meant to be rude. I was just curious about why you thought that `{"1"=>"2", "g"=>"h", "p"=>"v", "z"=>"z"}` was even close to `["z", "z", "z", "z"]`. My advice is that you learn more from your mistakes and thinking harder about a problem than from taking ready worked out SO solutions.

Comment: Dirk, take a look at my additional attempts.  I'm a n00b in progress-thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a method, use [slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D).

```
array_of_arrays.slice(3) #=> ["z", "z", "z", "z"]
```

Cary Swoveland's comment is alternate syntax for, and the more common way, to do the same thing:

```
array_of_arrays[3] #=> ["z", "z", "z", "z"]
```